# React Component doesn't rerender when the state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a small React project to get to learn more about it.

The project can make and view groups and in the groups you can store images, videos...

So the problem is when I open one of those groups and while I'm in it if I try to change to another group the component doesn't rerender and I have the same information.

Here's some of the code:

App:

```
function App() {
  const [chosenGroup, setChosenGroup] = useState({});

return (
    <Router>
      <Header setChosenGroup={setChosenGroup}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route 
          path="/Group/:group_name" 
          element={<Group group={chosenGroup} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );

}
```

Header (Where I choose the group):

```
function Header(props) {
  const setChosenGroup = props.setChosenGroup;

  return (
    <>
      <Top>
        <Image src={SiteLogo} />
        <GroupsBtn>
          MY GROUPS
        </GroupsBtn>
        <AllGroupsCont>
          <AllGroups>
            {myGroupDB.map((group, index) => {
              return (
                <StyledLink to={`/Group/${group.group_name}`} key={index}>
                  <Group onClick={() => {
                      setChosenGroup(group);
                    }}>
                    {group.group_name}
                  </Group>
                </StyledLink>
              );
            })}
          </AllGroups>
        </AllGroupsCont>
      </Top>
    </>
  )
}
```

Group:

```
function Group(props) {
  const param = useParams();
  
  return (
    <Main>
      <Top>
        <GroupTitle defaultValue={param.group_name} />
        <SaveButton className="saveButtonGroup" src={SaveIcon} />
        <DateCreated>Date created: {creationDate}</DateCreated>
      </Top>
      <Center>
        <GridContainer>
          {group.photos.map((photo) => {
            <Image src={photo.url} />;
          })}
        </GridContainer>
      </Center>
      <Bottom>
        <GoBackBtn onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>GO BACK</GoBackBtn>
        <SaveBtn>SAVE</SaveBtn>
      </Bottom>
    </Main>
  )
}
```

I checked the components in the browser and the state does indeed update so the problem is something else.

Comment: just to see if it makes a change. Try to send as a prop ```(newGroups)=>setChosenGroup(newGroup)``` instead of just  ```setChosenGroup```
I think u actually confusing the scopes of things. Probably my test would not work

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working :/

Comment: Is this the full and complete code? It seems to be missing some variable declarations. You pass `group` as a prop to the `Group` component, but I see nothing referencing from the `props` object. You also seem to be mixing route param usage and passing additional props. Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces any issues you are having that we could inspect and debug live.

Comment: No this isn't the full code I just copied the code where the problem occurs, what do you mean by mixing route param usage and passing additional props. Sorry I'm still new and don't quite understand some of this stuff

Answer (score 0):

This might solve it

```js
  <Group onClick={() => {
                      setChosenGroup({...group});
 }}>
```

Comment: No, it's still not working, the state changes and the info is different but the component doesn't rerender with the new info